# Javascript return in a function: factorial

Tags: javascript, function, loops, return, factorial

in this piece of code we can obtain a factorial of a number by plugging in our number to the function factorial(x).

From top to bottom I understand that if x = 0, we will get 1.

What I don't understand is 'return'. If x is 5 and we 'return' 5 * factorial(5-1), does it mean it is saying return 5 * 4 * 3...and so on until 0? How does the inner function operate?

I'm not sure how simple of a question this is but I'm having a hard time getting this to wrap around my head.

```
function factorial(x)   
{   

  if (x === 0)  
 {  
    return 1;  
 }  
  return x * factorial(x-1);  

}  
console.log(factorial(5));
```

Comment: Genuine question: do you understand recursion?

Comment: `does it mean it is saying return 5 * 4 * 3...and so on until 0?` yes and when it reaches 0, 1 is returned

Comment: Pretty much identical to [Factorial Code works but why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770052/factorial-code-works-but-why) SO is not well-suited to learning programming concepts. Those tend to be too broad.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado No, this is the first exercise problems in a list of recursion practices.

Comment: yes, the function calls itself 6 times and the number decreases by 1 until 0. so the final output like `5*4*3*2*1` which stays in stack and return 120.

Comment: @RaymondChen excuse my ignorance but what does SO stand for? And thank you for the link

Comment: SO stand for stack overflow

Comment: Imagine x = 1 then it will return. 1 * 1. If x= 2 return 2*1*1… and so on